# How can I get Terraform's 'cloudinit_config' data source to use an actual user-data script in my local directory?

Tags: terraform, cloud-init

Here's my cloudinit_config module in my Terraform code:

**main.tf**

```
data "cloudinit_config" "example" {
  gzip          = false
  base64_encode = true

  part {
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
    filename     = "/var/atlassian/application-data/jira/example.sh"
    content  = <<-EOF
      #!/bin/bash
      echo "Hello World"
    EOF
  }
}
```

I'm referencing the example they use in their [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/cloudinit/latest/docs/data-sources/cloudinit_config) where you write the bash commands in-line in the `content` argument. However, I have a user-data script (**userdata.sh**) that's pretty long and I'd prefer to have the *cloudinit_config* data source just reference/run that script instead of me having to have it all in-line. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use [file](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/file) for that:

```
content = file("${path.module}/path/to/userdata.sh")
```